# can not get rows from python dataframe using row index

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe

i read data from csv to python dataframe, and set index_col to create multilevel index, here is the result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path1= "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\ml-1m\\ZTXDMEMPEE.csv"
frame1 = pd.read_csv(path1,encoding='utf8',index_col=['MGR_CNUM','CNUM'])
frame1
```

[image]

when i use method 'ix' to get rows using row index, i get incorrect result,

```
frame1.ix['002263796']
```

[image]

Comment: It's the correct result, but your index in the original data frame isn't sorted, i.e., the slice of data for which `MGR_CNUM == 002263796` isn't all grouped together. Check the output of `frame1.sort_index()`.

Comment: right, i didn't noticed they are not grouped together, thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off. Absolutely do not use `.ix` for anything other than mixed label and integer location selection. Choose `iloc` or `loc`. Your result appears to be correct as indexing selection works by choosing all the rows that have that index. In this case, the outer level index.